Physical volume size lost after reboot
Context
I am running a Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.5 system in a VM on a VMWare ESXI.
I needed more space on a precise logical volume called lv_pmp on that VM :
$ lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0   80G  0 disk
├─sda1                         8:1    0  600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                         8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                         8:3    0 78,4G  0 part
  ├─VGslash-lv_root          253:0    0 19,5G  0 lvm  /
  ├─VGslash-lv_swap          253:1    0    4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─VGslash-lv_usr           253:2    0    8G  0 lvm  /usr
  ├─VGslash-lv_srv           253:3    0    2G  0 lvm  /srv
  ├─VGslash-lv_home          253:4    0    2G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─VGslash-lv_opt           253:5    0    4G  0 lvm  /opt
  ├─VGslash-lv_tmp           253:6    0    4G  0 lvm  /tmp
  ├─VGslash-lv_var_log_audit 253:7    0  512M  0 lvm  /var/log/audit
  ├─VGslash-lv_var_log       253:8    0    1G  0 lvm  /var/log
  ├─VGslash-lv_vartmp        253:9    0 10,4G  0 lvm  /var/tmp
  ├─VGslash-lv_var           253:10   0    3G  0 lvm  /var
  └─VGslash-lv_pmp           253:11   0   20G  0 lvm  /pmp
sr0                           11:0    1 1024M  0 rom

So I resized the disk of the VM to 500G in the VSphere properties which appeared on the sda part :
$ lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0  500G  0 disk
├─sda1                         8:1    0  600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                         8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                         8:3    0 78,4G  0 part
  ├─VGslash-lv_root          253:0    0 19,5G  0 lvm  /
  ├─VGslash-lv_swap          253:1    0    4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─VGslash-lv_usr           253:2    0    8G  0 lvm  /usr
  ├─VGslash-lv_srv           253:3    0    2G  0 lvm  /srv
  ├─VGslash-lv_home          253:4    0    2G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─VGslash-lv_opt           253:5    0    4G  0 lvm  /opt
  ├─VGslash-lv_tmp           253:6    0    4G  0 lvm  /tmp
  ├─VGslash-lv_var_log_audit 253:7    0  512M  0 lvm  /var/log/audit
  ├─VGslash-lv_var_log       253:8    0    1G  0 lvm  /var/log
  ├─VGslash-lv_vartmp        253:9    0 10,4G  0 lvm  /var/tmp
  ├─VGslash-lv_var           253:10   0    3G  0 lvm  /var
  └─VGslash-lv_pmp           253:11   0   20G  0 lvm  /pmp
sr0                           11:0    1 1024M  0 rom

Then I resized the sda3 physical volume to match the newly added disk space with
$ resizepart /dev/sda 3 1000000000
$ pvresize /dev/sda3

$ lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0   500G  0 disk
├─sda1                         8:1    0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                         8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                         8:3    0 476,9G  0 part
  ├─VGslash-lv_root          253:0    0  19,5G  0 lvm  /
  ├─VGslash-lv_swap          253:1    0     4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─VGslash-lv_usr           253:2    0     8G  0 lvm  /usr
  ├─VGslash-lv_srv           253:3    0     2G  0 lvm  /srv
  ├─VGslash-lv_home          253:4    0     2G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─VGslash-lv_opt           253:5    0     4G  0 lvm  /opt
  ├─VGslash-lv_tmp           253:6    0     4G  0 lvm  /tmp
  ├─VGslash-lv_var_log_audit 253:7    0   512M  0 lvm  /var/log/audit
  ├─VGslash-lv_var_log       253:8    0     1G  0 lvm  /var/log
  ├─VGslash-lv_vartmp        253:9    0  10,4G  0 lvm  /var/tmp
  ├─VGslash-lv_var           253:10   0     3G  0 lvm  /var
  └─VGslash-lv_pmp           253:11   0    20G  0 lvm  /pmp
sr0                           11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

I increased the lv_pmp logical volume size :
$ lvextend /dev/mapper/VGslash-lv_pmp -l+100%FREE

And refreshed the file system to let it detect the new size :
$ xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/VGslash-lv_pmp

So far so good I got the size I expected on the lv_pmp logical volume :
$ lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0   500G  0 disk
├─sda1                         8:1    0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                         8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                         8:3    0 476,9G  0 part
  ├─VGslash-lv_root          253:0    0  19,5G  0 lvm  /
  ├─VGslash-lv_swap          253:1    0     4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─VGslash-lv_usr           253:2    0     8G  0 lvm  /usr
  ├─VGslash-lv_srv           253:3    0     2G  0 lvm  /srv
  ├─VGslash-lv_home          253:4    0     2G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─VGslash-lv_opt           253:5    0     4G  0 lvm  /opt
  ├─VGslash-lv_tmp           253:6    0     4G  0 lvm  /tmp
  ├─VGslash-lv_var_log_audit 253:7    0   512M  0 lvm  /var/log/audit
  ├─VGslash-lv_var_log       253:8    0     1G  0 lvm  /var/log
  ├─VGslash-lv_vartmp        253:9    0  10,4G  0 lvm  /var/tmp
  ├─VGslash-lv_var           253:10   0     3G  0 lvm  /var
  └─VGslash-lv_pmp           253:11   0 418,4G  0 lvm  /pmp
sr0                           11:0    1  1024M  0 rom    

Problem
The issue comes as soon as I reboot the system : it appears to lose the size changes I made to the sda3 physical volume, which in consequence prevents the lv_pmp logical volume from being mounted (as it assumes it does not have enough space on the parent PV) :
$ lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0   500G  0 disk
├─sda1                         8:1    0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                         8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                         8:3    0  76,9G  0 part
  ├─VGslash-lv_root          253:0    0  19,5G  0 lvm  /
  ├─VGslash-lv_swap          253:1    0     4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─VGslash-lv_usr           253:2    0     8G  0 lvm  /usr
  ├─VGslash-lv_srv           253:3    0     2G  0 lvm  /srv
  ├─VGslash-lv_home          253:4    0     2G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─VGslash-lv_opt           253:5    0     4G  0 lvm  /opt
  ├─VGslash-lv_tmp           253:6    0     4G  0 lvm  /tmp
  ├─VGslash-lv_var_log_audit 253:7    0   512M  0 lvm  /var/log/audit
  ├─VGslash-lv_var_log       253:8    0     1G  0 lvm  /var/log
  ├─VGslash-lv_vartmp        253:9    0  10,4G  0 lvm  /var/tmp
  └─VGslash-lv_var           253:10   0     3G  0 lvm  /var
sr0                           11:0    1  1024M  0 rom 

Workaround
It is possible to get it back in shape by executing the following commands manually after the reboot :
### Re-apply physical volume changes
$ resizepart /dev/sda 3 1000000000
$ pvresize /dev/sda3
### Re-scan logical volumes
$ vgscan --mknodes -v
$ vgchange -a y

Question
Why is this happening ? And what can I do to prevent it ?
I do not know if this is related to the OS itself or to the VM environment or to some other factors I do not control, any advice on that regard would also help.
The workaround above is not really satisfying, even if I could place that in a script at startup, having to do this action every boot does not feel right: it does not make sense to me that a volume size change would not persist after a reboot.

resizepart does not update on-disk structures. It only makes changes to the kernel live structures. Consulting man resizepart:

resizepart tells the Linux kernel about the new size of the specified partition. The command is a simple wrapper around the "resize partition" ioctl.
This command doesn’t manipulate partitions on a block device.

You have to use fdisk (or any other partition editor) to change partition on disk, and then update kernel view using resizepart (or kpartx, or partprobe, or reboot).
There is a tool called growpart which does both, and online.

Thank you, fdisk seems to be available on my system, I will try to use it for that purpose and report back on this topic.

I ended up doing it with parted as suggested here for OL8 systems: https://access.redhat.com/articles/1190213, but it is indeed working as intended now. With this tool I could simply replace the step using resizepart and go directly to pvresize right after.
